# Help using offline QGIS API documentation

Tags: qgis, qt, documentation

I have downloaded the [QGIS documentation](http://qgis.org/api/) for offline usage, am I correct in thinking that the qgis.qch file is the one I need to open to view the documentation, using Qt Assistant?

I have a [Qt installer](http://www.qt.io/download/), where it lists a bunch of packages to install but Qt Assistant isn't listed.

(i did check if this has already been asked/answered - as far as I can tell it hasn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QtAssistant is now included in QtCreator (I don't know if a standalone exist again).

Open QtCreator, Tools -> Options -> Help -> Documentation -> Add... and choose qgis.qch.

The documentation will now be accessible from the help pannel.